# About Clonezilla and how store the backup

Tags: debian, backup, clonezilla

I've never used Clonezilla before.

When storing a backup, Clonezilla needs a free partition or free space? I mean, I have a disk for backups with only one partition. Do I have to create a partition for save the backup (what means have 2 partitions) or it is stored just like a normal HUGE file?

Answer (score 0):

The ways I've used Clonezilla in the past have been a) saving a drive image to another (bigger) drive, or b) saving a drive image across a network to a file server.

I'm not 100% sure, but I don't think you can save an image of a partition or drive to the partition you are imaging!

Comment: No no xD I have two disks,  one with system and swap partitions, and other with only one partition. I want to backup the system partition and store it in the second disk,  but reading about Clonezilla usage I don't have clear if I have to create and specific partition for the backup or if it will be stored as a normal file in the partition I havr already.

Comment: Ok I tried already, it stores as a file.

Comment: That little tidbit - that you had a second drive to store the image on - would have been nice to know originally, as it would have significantly changed the answer given.